# How to make a ACF Block default and mandatory for a specific post type

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

So I made this new ACF Hero Block for a site that I’m working on, and I’m trying to figure out how to make it default and always present in a specific post type – in this case, the “accommodations” post type. Basically, I want this block to show up every time I make a new post in that post type, preferably right at the top. But honestly, I have no idea if that’s even possible. I’ve tried editing the block.json file and even tinkering with the functions.php, but I haven’t gotten any results.

I am using ACF Pro 6.0

Does anyone know if this is possible? Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks a lot

*The block.json*

```
{
  "name": "acf/hero",
  "title": "Ferienpark Hero",
  "description": "Hero Block",
  "style": ["file:./hero.css"],
  "category": "Ferienpark",
  "icon": "cover-image",
  "keywords": ["hero", "header", "image"],
  "supports": {
    "align": true,
    "anchor": true,
    "html": true,
    "postTypes": ["accommodations", "post"],
    "default": true
  },

  "acf": {
    "mode": "edit",
    "renderTemplate": "hero.php"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `template` parameter when registering custom post type, for example :

```
'template'            => array(
        array(
            'acf/banner-block',
            array(
                'mode' => 'preview',
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'core/heading',
            array(
                'level'   => 3,
                'content' => 'About this Event',
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

You can read the documentation here :
https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-templates/#custom-post-types